# Kfold cross-validation and SVM on list of strings python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation

**Goal:** I am trying to run kfold cross validation on a list of strings `X, y`  and get the cross validation score using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold 

X = ["hey", "join now", "hello", "join today"]
y = ["n", "y", "n", "y"]
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2)

for train, test in skf.split(X,y): 
    print("%s %s" % (train,test)) 

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)

scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=2)
```

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

**Question:** Is it possible to run kfold cross validation and svm on a list of strings? Or do I need a different procedure?

I'm new to sklearn and I have read many tutorials including this one http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/cross_validation.html but I'm still not sure if I am doing this correctly.

Comment: No. The `y` (labels or targets) can be a string but not X (sample wise features). You need to convert them to float somehow. Maybe get the tfidf or frequencies of words. See [text processing](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here isn't the cross-validation, it is your input data. As @VivekKumar pointed out you need to convert your data to some kind of numerical format. Scikit has tools for converting text in the [`sklearn.feature_extraction.text`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_extraction.text) module. I won't get into the details of what each does here, but the suggestion of using TFIDF is generally pretty sound.

In short TFIDF is a way to assign a each word a value that relates to how important that word is to a document based on the entire corpus of documents. I will point out that the science behind vectorizing strings/documents is quite deep and you should really take the time to at least get familiar with things like stemming and lemmatization, tokenization, and n-grams.

In this case the simplest example would be to use the out of the box [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) in sklearn to process your strings before training your model.

```
from sklean.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
X_vec = tfidf.fit_transform(X)
X_vec.toarray()
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.6191303 ,  0.78528828,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.6191303 ,  0.        ,  0.78528828]])
cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X_vec, y, cv=2)
array([ 0.5,  0.5])
```

That should get you started, but again I want to point out that in NLP tuning your text processing steps is just as critical if not more so than  tuning your models hyperparameters.